# Prove that it is possible to divide integral area into two equal parts

Tags: real-analysis

Assuming $f$ is locally integrable on interval $<a,b>$, I'd like to show that it is always possible to divide it into two equal parts in terms of enclosed areas.

In other words, I'd like to show there exists $x \in [a,b]$ with $\int_a^x f(t)\ dt = \int_x^b f(t)\ d(t)$.

I got stuck composing a help function $h(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\ dt - \int_x^b f(t)\ d(t)$. I thought it might be useful, but I don't really know how could apply the mean value theorem to show that it is possible to find such an $x$ that $g(x)=0$.

P.S.: I also think it only works on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $h(x)$ you defined is continuous on $[a,b]$. At $a$, it is $-\int_a^b f(t)\ dt$. At $b$, it is $\int_a^b f(t)\ dt$. So, if the integral over $[a,b]$ is not zero, you're done by the intermediate value theorem.

If the integral is zero over $[a,b]$, the point $x=a$ will work.

Comment: Ok, I see - it's because the two results are exact the opposite.

Does this also work on ]a,b[?

Comment: @randomguy I think so. Just extend $f(x)$ to be $0$ at $a$ and $b$ to get a function on $[a,b]$, then apply the same argument.

Comment: but the intermediate value theorem doesn't work on open intervals??

Comment: @randomguy That's why I extended the domain of integration to a closed interval.

Comment: @randomguy I believe $[a,b]$ is bigger than $(a,b)$.

Comment: <> is either [], [), (] or (). And I think it can only work on []. Precisely because I have to extend it first to be 0 on the both boundaries points, it can happen that we deal with such a f, where the proof doesn't work.

Comment: @randomguy Could you give an example? (You won't be able to, because one doesn't exist. The argument I gave works.)

Comment: @randomguy Also, that appears to be non-standard notation. (And you should use \langle and \rangle to make the brackets, not < and >.)

Comment: It's predefined like this. What about if f is not defined in one of the boundaries?

Comment: @randomguy As I said, you just set it to be $0$ at each endpoint.

Comment: $\int_0^1 {1 \over 1-x} dx = \infty$ Can we split $\infty$ in halves?

Comment: @randomguy That diverges on the open interval, too.

Comment: @randomguy Sorry, misread locally integrable as integrable. My argument works in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How are $h(a)$ and $h(b)$ related?